# Blank Magento Page without error

Tags: magento2, module, custom

After enabling the module created, browsing back to the page gives me blank page instead. Viewing the source of the page gives me basic html tags.

[image: public view]

[image: view source]

Comment: enable developer more or check the log

Comment: remove # from app/bootstrap.php ini_set('display_errors', 1);  and check for the error on frontend.

Comment: thanks, but I'm still unable to display the error message.possible that html tags/php loads properly. I think we need to check out the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using XAMPP, first, change **`localhost`** to **`127.0.0.1`** or your unit **`IP address`**

If in case the admin panel is not accessible, you can go to your **`database`** and go to **`core_config_data`** table, then locate **`web/secure/base_url`** and **`web/unsecure/base_url`** and change value of **`localhost`** from there.

If you face an error after the changes above:

You can try editing the Validator file from **`vendor`** folder with namespace

> **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File**

At around line **138** replace the code with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

save then **cache:flush**

Comment: have tried your resolution thru database replacement but it caused the site for too many redirections. and for the vendor folder, I've replaced with this code after I did the installation.

Comment: did you got any errors in your browser's network tab?

Comment: it loads without an error from behind. there's no issue with the custom module but when it was enabled, I can only see a blank page.

Comment: you can try to debug it by enabling developer mode in Magento 2. or you can also open index.php inside your magento root directory then add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` or other way is to go to pub/errors directory and rename local.xml.sample file to local.xml then refresh the page to see the errors